# Just erased /var/tmp dir, what to do?

Tags: tmp

While cleaning up the system for about 7 hrs,  I "cleaned up" the \var\tmp folder , which has no backup.

Despite the answer looks as very simple and straightforward - just `reboot` and forget, 
I'm affraid to do so since it is live server and if something is not OK, I'll have an extremely unpleasant night, which to involve the system upgrade, I planned to do next weekend anyway :).

Can anyone reassure me, just reboot wont make any trouble?

Comment: /var/tmp is one place that systemd keeps track of services. Reboot may be wise.

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything in that folder to persist anyway...

Comment: All my `/var/tmp` contains are empty directories, with a time stamp from when the system was booted. I would say go ahead.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, There were about 5GB of strange files from systemd and apache... still have no clue how that might have happened